# Iterating over all filter_input variables

Tags: php

Using `$_POST`, I can iterate through all `POST` variables with

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // do something
}
```

But is there anything similar for iterating through every `$key` such that `filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key)` gives a variable from `POST`?

Obiviously I could use

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
    if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, $key) {
        $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key);
        // do something
    }
}
```

But this would not always be sufficient. If for example some of the `$_POST` keys had been unset, it would be useful to find out which keys were originally available, as they would still be accessible through `filter_input`. Besides, I would like to never have to access any superglobals directly.

Comment: I guess you mean `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $_POST);` but it has the same limitations as I mentioned above.

Comment: If you give an example of $_POST variables and the output you would like I would be able to help you out here but your wording is confusing me.

Comment: I don't want a particular output, i just want a way to iterate through all `POST` keys without using `$_POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a design problem, using FILTER_INPUT is the same as using SUPERGLOBALS. If you want to unset any $_POST variable, you have to keep a copy of that variable before unset it. There is nothing wrong to parse $_POST as is:

```
   // backup your $_POST (or $_POST keys)
   $_post_backup = $_POST;

   // remove 'foo'
   unset($_POST['foo']);

   // itereate
   foreach($_post_backup as $key => $value) {
       $filtered_value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key);
       // do something
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this on the developer site of Paypal IPN:

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
```

I tested it and it works. Don't know if it is failsafe but in most cases it is more than good.
You still have to filter the input but now you can do it with filter_input_array